# Using command as parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pipe

I am trying to move some files to a *relative* subfolder recursivly.

I want to use the `get-location` command and combine it with a string (*"\foo_1"*), while using it as a parameter.

So `get-location`  should result in "*D:\foo_2*" so that the result is "*D:\foo_2\foo_1*"

All while being a parameter of a separate command:

`Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.wav" -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination (get-location + "string")`

I know i could just use variables, but i really want to understand this (if there is an answer). Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sub-expression, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.wav" -Recurse | 
    Move-Item -Destination "$(Get-Location)\foo_1"
```

The structure `$(...)` tells PowerShell to execute the contents of the brackets first (i.e. run `Get-Location`) then substitute the result into the string.  Note that you must use double-quotes as this functionality doesn't work with single-quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks! The $(...) did it for me 